# inserting csv files into mysql db

Tags: mysql, excel, macos, csv

I have csv file with delimiter ';'. It looks following (third column should be empty):

```
  id;theme_name;description

5cbde2fe-b70a-5245-bbde-c2504a4bced1;DevTools;allow web developers to test and debug their code. They are different from website builders and integrated development environments (IDEs) in that they do not assist in the direct creation of a webpage, rather they are tools used for testing the user interface of a website or web application.

c8bfc406-aaa6-5cf9-94c3-09fc54b934e7;AI;
```

Here is my script for inserting data from csv into db:

```
 mysql -u ${MYSQL_USER} --password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD} ${MYSQL_DATABASE} --local-infile=1 -h ${MYSQL_HOST} -e"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/init_data/$file' INTO TABLE $table_name  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

When I'm making SELECT statement, Im getting carriage return (\r) in last column in response:

Here is response from mysql

```
{
  "themeName": "DevTools",
   "description": "allow web developers to test and debug their code. They are different from website builders and integrated development environments (IDEs) in that they do not assist in the direct creation of a webpage, rather they are tools used for testing the user interface of a website or web application.\r"
}, {
    "themeName": "AI",
    "description": "\r"
}
```

When I add delimiter ';' after last column in csv file, carriage return disappeared from response.

for example:  `c8bfc406-aaa6-5cf9-94c3-09fc54b934e7;AI;;`

**Why mysql add  \r into third column ?**

**Is there any possible way how to solve it ? (except replace in select statement)**

Thanks

Comment: Your second line in the CSV file does not have the same (3) columns. This functionality is dependant upon the lines in your file complying to the rules. If all the lines are not the same format you will have to write some code with relevant inteligence to load the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly I removed all lines with two columns in csv and its the same. In my opinion when mysql is inserting lines into db from scv and if it not see delimiter in last column,   it takes it as  new line (carriage return) and append it.

Comment: Not quite, there will be a newline in those lines, either `\r\n` or `\r` depending on where the file was created (Windows or *nix) It is that that is being picked up

Comment: Is there a SO tag for line-terminators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your CSV file comes from Windows.  Those files have `\r\n` at the end of every line.

Add this to your command ...

```
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
```

and things should work.  If they don't try this

```
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

On UNIX-derived systems (like Linux) the default `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` works.

On Mac systems you need `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'`.

If you add a trailing `;` column separator you create a fourth column in your CSV. But the table you're loading only has three columns, so `LOAD DATA INFILE` ignores that fourth column, which has a `\r` in it.

Why this difference, you ask?  Old-timey teletype devices (the original terminals for MS-DOS and UNIX) needed a <kbd>Return</kbd> code to move the print head back to the first column, and a <kbd>Newline</kbd> code to move the paper up one line.  The UNIX Bell Labs team decided their tty driver would add the extra <kbd>Return</kbd> code so lines ended with a particular single character. MS-DOS's team (umm, Bill Gates) left them both in.

Why Mac with just <kbd>Return</kbd>? Maybe somebody knows.

Comment: Thanks for response! I'm using MacOS. I created csv file using excel for MAC.  I'm playing with LINES TERMINATED BY but it does not work. When I hit API via postman I still get carriage return in response.

Comment: It doesn't work **yet**. Keep trying. This line termination stuff is a notorious pain in the *ss.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

According to @O.Jones answer I needed to add `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'` but alsoI need to add \n

```
  mysql -u ${MYSQL_USER} --password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD} ${MYSQL_DATABASE} --local-infile=1 -h ${MYSQL_HOST} -e"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/init_data/$file' INTO TABLE $table_name  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";
```